# Changing Background Color based on Temperature Ranges

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting some API information from Weather Underground and was wondering if it is possible to change the background color of the entire `body` through jQuery by using the information provided by the API.

What I would like to do is set a class on the `body` tag based on a certain range of Temperature that is returned via the API. So for example:

```
"current_observation": {
    "image": {
    "url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
    "title":"Weather Underground",
    "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
    },
    "display_location": {
    "full":"Bowling Green, KY",
    "city":"Bowling Green",
    "state":"KY",
    "state_name":"Kentucky",
    "country":"US",
    "country_iso3166":"US",
    "zip":"42101",
    "latitude":"37.02899933",
    "longitude":"-86.46366119",
    "elevation":"154.00000000"
    },
    "observation_location": {
    "full":"Ridgeview Drive, Bowling Green, Kentucky",
    "city":"Ridgeview Drive, Bowling Green",
    "state":"Kentucky",
    "country":"US",
    "country_iso3166":"US",
    "latitude":"36.993744",
    "longitude":"-86.522827",
    "elevation":"714 ft"
    },
    "estimated": {
    },
    "station_id":"KKYBOWLI7",
    "observation_time":"Last Updated on May 24, 2:25 PM CDT",
    "observation_time_rfc822":"Thu, 24 May 2012 14:25:18 -0500",
    "observation_epoch":"1337887518",
    "local_time_rfc822":"Thu, 24 May 2012 14:25:29 -0500",
    "local_epoch":"1337887529",
    "local_tz_short":"CDT",
    "local_tz_long":"America/Chicago",
    "local_tz_offset":"-0500",
    "weather":"Clear",
    "temperature_string":"86.8 F (30.4 C)",
    "temp_f":86.8
```

That is some info I am pulling in. The very last one `temp_f` is what I want to focus on.

An example of ranges is - 80 through 90 should display `background:#dd7f35`

I've attempted to set up custom variables for this but always wind up breaking things. I can't seem to figure out how to set up a variable using the information pulled in from the JSON (if that's even possible since `temp_f` uses decimals.)

Here is how I am calling the JSON

```
$().ready(function(){ 
    $.getJSON("http://api.wunderground.com/api/[MY API KEY]/conditions/q/autoip.json?callback=?",
    function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, json) {
        content = '<h1>' + json.icon + '</h1>';
        content += '<img src=' + json.icon_url +'>';
        content += '<p>' + json.temp_f + '<p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#area");
        });
    console.log(data)
    });
});
```

Here is something I have tried

```
var backDrop = ' + json.temp_f + '
```

I used `+ json.temp_f +`because that is pulling in the temp just fine for the regular HTML but I can kind of assume that's not going to work in this case?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var backDrop = json.temp_f;
```

Just get rid of the quotes and the pluses.

Or you could do something like this:

```
 var colorOutput = '';

 if(json.temp_f < 20){
     colorOutput = 'blue'; //use hex color
 }else if(json.temp_f >=20 && json.temp_f < 60){
     colorOutput = 'orange'; //use hex color
 }

 $('#colorMeElement').css('background',colorOutput);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up CSS styles for each range-color combination, like .range_80_90 that has background:#dd7f35. Then you can create the class dynamically in your script and apply it to the appropriate element.

Comment: This, and then just add the class to body like this `$(body).addClass('.range_80_90');`

Comment: OK, thanks @IsNull makes sense and is a far easier way than what I have been trying. Thanks tons.

Comment: @IsNull -- I've been trying this but can't seem to get it to work. I have all the styles set up, but can't get it to add the class to the `body`. Can you give an example?

Comment: a normal jQuery .addClass should do the trick:
`$(body).addClass('.range_80_90');`